# how to ask different questions with TestWebSocketFrame in netty

Tags: java, netty

I am using for writing to a socket.

```
channels.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(String msg));
```

and in my webpage (that is displayed to the client) I obtain the data from the event(event.data) and display it in the text area(say T1). but i have 2 text area's (say T1 and T2) and I want to display different data in the two of them.I cant figure out a way to do this. So can if i could get some implementation or some way to get the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encode in the WebSocketFrame some "marker" that can be used to detect to which frame the text goes. For example you could use Json or something like this